# flash gallery slider on cursor movement

Tags: flash

can anyone help me about the flash gallery slider on cursor movement either left or right direction like this website www.solutionsdc.com please help me.

Comment: Questions need specifics to get any help. What are you asking, and what have you already done to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well that should not be to hard, just map the mouseX to the (inversed) x property of the gallery and you also need a multiplier since the gallery clip is wider than the total movement of the mouse.

Your multiplier would be something like

```
private var _multiplier:Number = widthOfGallery / totalMouseMovementWidth;
```

And then on enter frame or mouse move:

```
gallery.x = -stage.mouseX * _multiplier;
```

Well, that is roughly (you will need some conditioning) how I think it's made, try it out and tell me if it works.